# Amplifier circuit with clamping output signal

Tags: power-supply, transistors, common-emitter

[image: With 9V component]

[image: With power supply]

Hello. I am currently studying transistors and working on a Common Emitter amplifier for our project. We are asked to create our own power supply circuit and use it to power our own amplifier circuit. My output signal is clamping as shown in picture 2 and I don't know how optimize it so that it will have an output similar to the first picture. The first picture is the one connected to a 9V DC component, while the second one is connected to the AC-DC converter power supply. Any explanations on this?

*Edit: We are only required to simulate our circuits. I am currently using LTSpice to simulate the circuit.

Comment: Where is your 'oscilloscope probe' in the second image for the blue trace? I don't think it's the same as in the first image.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Where is the signal which is generating the blue trace in both images? For the first image I imagine it is at the node labelled output, but in the second it has 5 V DC as well as the sinusoidal signal which makes me think it's at the collector of Q1 instead.

Comment: Both of the output are the same. The power supply in the AC-DC converter (second image) also supplies 9V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the following. In your first simulation, you are not using the option *"Start external DC supply voltages at 0V"* in your simulation configuration panel, and in your second simulation your are indirectly using it because of the non-ideal voltage supply starting from 0V. If you want to double check it, just enable this option in your first simulation and you should get at similar outcome.

**What is happening in your first simulation**

By not enabling the aforementioned option, upon solving the operating point, at t=0 the collector voltage is set to 9V, the base to approx. 1.5V and the output node to 0V. So basically, your op-amp's operating point is already set and it is ready to amplify. Everything looks nice, and the applied signal does not drive your opamp out of its operating point.

**What is happening in your second simulation**

By (indirectly) setting the supply voltage to 0V, you are experiencing something called capacitive coupling, which basically means that a capacitor will do everything to keep the voltage between its terminal to stay the same. As the collector voltage at start up ramps up together with your supply voltage, so does the node `output`. By the time the circuit has reached its operating point, the output voltage already has some offset, which is basically what you see in your simulation.

**How to solve it / avoid it**

Depending on the application, if you are going to build the circuit later, you should consider enabling the aforementioned option because it is a closer representation of a real circuit (The voltage does just appear suddenly in all nodes of the circuit). In your case you could either find the biasing point with the option enabled, or remove the output capacitor and mathematically determine the AC amplified signal by subtracting the DC component from your collector's voltage.